# Mocha Tests Are Timing Out

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm running Node.js 4.0 so it supports generators now.

I've tried gulp-mocha-co and also recently removed that as well as upgraded to Node 4.0 since it supports generators now.

Either way, as soon as I started to try to make my mocha tests generator friendly I get timeouts on all those tests after adding the * to make my mocha unit tests generators.  I noticed that it doesn't even run my test implementation code.  It gets to the *function() of my test and that's when it just sits and times out.

I am using [gulp-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-mocha) right now.

**myTests.js**

```
"use strict";

var chai = require('chai'),
    should = chai.should(),
    testUtil = require('../../../test/testUtilities'),
    carUseCase = require('../../../src/usecases/carGet'),
    gateway= require('../../../test/gateway'),
    carRequestModel = require('../../../src/models/http/request/carRequest');

describe('Get Car by Id', function() {

    it('should return no car when no cars exist', function*(done){
        var cars = [];

        inMemoryGateway.data(cars);
        carUseCase.gateway(gateway);

        var request = testUtil.createCarRequest();
        var responseModel = yield carUseCase.find(request);
        should.not.exist(responseModel.cars);

        var request = testUtil.createCarRequest(0, "", "", "");
        var responseModel = yield carUseCase.find(request);
        should.not.exist(responseModel.cars);

        done();
    });
```

**gulp.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    mocha = require('gulp-mocha');

...
    gulp.task('mocha-unit', function() {
        process.env.PORT = 5001;
        return gulp.src([config.test.src.unit], { read: false })
            .pipe(mocha({
                reporter: config.test.mocha.reporter,
                ui: 'bdd'
            }))
    });
```

**carGet.js**

```
var car = require('../entities/car'),
    realGateway = require('../../src/gateways/carGateway'),
    carResponse = require('../../src/models/http/response/carResponse'),
    _gateway;

module.exports = {
    find: function *(carRequest){

        carResponse.http.statusCode = 200;

        var entity = yield _gateway.find(carRequest.id);

        if(!entity.cars || entity.cars.length == 0){
            entity.cars = null;
            carResponse.http.statusCode = 204;
        }

        carResponse.cars = entity.cars;

        return carResponse;
    }
};
```

**gatewayTestDouble.js**

```
'use strict';

var _data;

module.exports = {
    data: function(data){
        _data = data
    },
    find: function *(id) {
        var found = [];

        if(id == null && hasData(_data)){
            yield _data;
            return;
        }

        if(!id && !isPositiveNumber(id)){
            yield found;
            return;
        }

        if(isPositiveNumber(id) && hasData(_data)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
                if (_data[i].id === id)
                    found.push(_data[i]);
            }
        }

        yield found;
    }
};
```

**Error**

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things going on here.

1. Since you've declared `done` as a callback argument, Mocha waits for it to be called, which never happens because...
2. Mocha doesn't support generators as callbacks. All it sees is that your callback returned an iterator. Since Mocha doesn't run the iterator to completion, the `done()` call is never reached.

Mocha *does* however support functions that return promises, as a mutually-exclusive alternative to functions that declare `done` in their arg lists.

The [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) utility can wrap generators that iterate multiple promises, turning them into functions that return a single promise.

In order to work, don't declare `done` in the arg list, then import `co` and do something like this:

```
it('should foo', co.wrap(function*() {
  var foo = yield somethingThatReturnsAPromise();
  // do something with foo
}));
```

Note that you could alternatively do the below, and Mocha wouldn't be able to tell the difference:

```
it('should foo', co.wrap(function*() {
  return somethingThatReturnsAPromise().then(function(foo) {
    // do something with foo
  });
}));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks I'm still trying to wrap my head around generators more and also co.

Comment: like what the heck is a co-generator-function?

Comment: Not sure what "co-generator-function" refers to, but generators passed to co should only yield promises otherwise co will throw an error. Whereas normally you can yield any type of value from a generator.